# Properties of a good object for tapping (stylus) on touchscreen keyboard?

Tags: touchpad, touchscreen, input, input-device

I was thinking of inputting somewhat larger text on a touchscreen, and since I have fat and clumsy fingers, that will be a total pain to type by hand/fingers.

So I thought, it would be much easier for me to hold a pen-like object, and use that to tap on the touchscreen. Obviously, I would not want that object to be hard and sharp, else I'll damage the touchscreen.

So, I tried

- using a q-tip (cotton swab), dry - and the touchscreen didn't react.
- Got the q-tip wet with a bit of water - touchscreen didn't react.
- Tried to (very carefully) drag a screwdriver om the touchscreen, to see if metal makes a difference - touchscreen didn't react.
- Tried a various assortment of pens, and pencils (including the erasing rubber end) - touchscreen didn't react.

So, I was wondering - what would the properties of an object, that can serve as a tap/drag input tool on a touchscreen, be? Soft for one - but what are the properties required, so that the touchscreen would actually *react* to input, made using the object?

IIRC, touchpads can be implemented as "resistive" or "capacitive", but I do not know what property do they measure to provide input. Would that property be electric field? If so, could one use, say, an AA battery (don't have one with me to test) to provide input through a touchscreen?

Comment: Are you trying to make your own stylus?

Comment: There are touch gloves that has something in the fingers to make it work. You should investigate what they are to get your answer, or alternatively buy one and put something like a pen in one of the fingers.

Comment: Thanks @davidmneedham - yeah, I guess so (or find any common object to function as one); couldn't quite remember the word for "stylus", so thanks for mentioning - I have updated the title!

Comment: Thanks @LPChip - do you mean something like described on, say, https://www.tomsguide.com/us/pictures-story/1194-best-touchscreen-gloves.html ? Never heard about these before, will research - thanks!

Comment: Yup, exactly, those.

Answer (score 0):

From some comments by [Mokubai](https://superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai):

> The properties for capacitive screens is that the "prodding" device be somewhat conductive but not a direct short, hence "capacitive". Your fingers act like a moving charged capacitor able to affect a conductive pattern etched into the glass. For resistive screens they are simpler, there being an air-gap between layers that a poking device will distort and short the layers together at particular points.
>
> Typically the "smartphone stylus" pens are a conductive rubber compound tip connected to a metal tube. This acts like a (very small) capacitor in a similar way to your finger on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what device you are trying to operate, but just bear in mind that not all styluses and touchscreens are interoperable!

For example, the Samsung Galaxy Note series devices have a pen digitizer that runs independent from its touch digitizer.  The styluses themselves need to be magnetic induction type pens in order to even register a response; the pro to these are the amazingly precise and responsive touch tracking and precision, downside is that the tech is proprietary and OEM pens are fragile and expensive.

EDIT: I just realized what I stated above is slightly misleading.  While it's true there are two separate digitizers, capacitative styluses *may* still technically work on a Galaxy Note screen; it's just that it would trigger the **touch** digitizer rather than the **pen** digitizer.